How can I connect Emacs to a remote Emacs?
I have my primary Emacs running on a GNU/Linux host, where I have all the bells and whistles for all kinds of stuff;)
I do however need to compile some code that requires .NET-4.5, therefore I want to connect to another Emacs instance which runs on WSL2, where compilation is possible.
My question is
Can I connect a running Emacs to another Emacs?

I don't want to run an emacsclient, because then I don't have access to my own Emacs, which is more complete.
I don't want to transfer my entire config to the remote Emacs
I assume I can't use a remote compiler in a local Emacs, then being able to run and step through code. I can't really wrap my head around that is something which someone has made working;)

I'm not really sure what options I have and what direction I should take;)

If you can connect to the remote WSL2 with ssh, then you can use Tramp to run shells, compilation, etc in the WSL2 context. Maybe gdb, I've never tried.
